# Postgres "time zone at" isn't respecting mountain standard time when converting

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a column `starts_at` with a type of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` because it's representing the time of an appointment and should not change during a DST shift.

However, our library that handles recurring appointments needs this time in UTC. I am attempting to convert `starts_at` to UTC, but am seeing that I'm getting times representing MDT (daylight savings time) rather than MST (standard time).

For example, take the following:

`SELECT starts_at, timezone('America/Denver', starts_at) AS new_starts_at`

I would expect to get the following result:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| starts_at              | new_starts_at
--------------------------------------------------
| 2018-09-04 13:05:00    |  2018-09-04 20:05:00+00
```

Instead, I'm getting the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| starts_at              | new_starts_at
--------------------------------------------------
| 2018-09-04 13:05:00    |  2018-09-04 19:05:00+00
```

`new_starts_at` should be returning in `MST`, which would be `2018-09-04 20:05:00+00`. My impression was that using the Olsen timezone (`America/Denver`) would inform Postgres of whether or not there was a DST shift in place. If I replace `America/Denver` with `MST`, I see the correct result.

I'm sure this is just a misunderstanding of Postgres timezone types on my part. That said, thanks in advance for the education!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `timezone('America/Denver', starts_at)` interprets `starts_at` as being in Denver local time, the result is a `timestamp with time zone`.

Now when you output that value, it is transformed to your session time zone, which is UTC.

13:05 in Denver is 19:05 in UTC, which happens to be your session time zone.

During daylight savings time, Denver is offset 6 hours from UTC.

Comment: 13:05 Denver is 20:05 in UTC. During daylight savings time, it's 19:05

Comment: Right, and in September, daylight savings time was still in effect.